# Can a Ring of Spell Knowledge add spells to a sorcerer's known spell list

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer

I was wondering if a Ring of Spell Knowledge can add the spell within to a Sorcerer's spell list if it is an arcane spell and the sorcerer can cast the spell of that level.  I would say no, but one of my players was asking and in the item description it says "Through study, the wearer can gain the knowledge of a single spell in addition to those allotted by her class and level."
They argue that since you gain the knowledge of the spell it should be on their list.  I don't think this is right but I can't find anything to dispute it out right

Answer (score 5):

The *ring of spell knowledge* is intended to artificially extend a spontaneous caster's spell list. From the [item's description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-knowledge/) :

> Thereafter, the arcane spellcaster may cast the spell as though she knew the spell and it appeared on her class’ spell list.
>
> Arcane spells that do not appear on the wearer’s class list are treated as one level higher for all purposes (storage and casting).

Since they only retain the knowledge while wearing the ring, your player's sorcerer is effectively sacrificing an item slot so that they can know an extra spell... and even then, if it isn't normally a sorcerer spell they must use a higher slot.